# prometheus alert rules and config ui tools?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Colleagues, someone can suggest some UI for easy setup alerts prometeia and json certainly cool, but it's uncomfortable, and I think not only for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most common mix is `Prometheus` and `Grafana`.

[Grafana](https://grafana.com/) also providing plugi-in for [Prometheus](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/prometheus) and [Prometheus AlertManager](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource/installation). You can find many tutorials online with installation, configuration and integration of both like [this](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/configure-prometheus-monitoring-with-grafana/).

You could also check other UI's like [Kibana](https://github.com/pjhampton/kibana-prometheus-exporter#installing) or [Kiali](https://kiali.io/), however I think `Grafana` would be best for your needs.

Comment: all this I already use, but I want just to add rules, such as Zabbix.
for example, changes of name alert Manager to do so: https://coreos.com/tectonic/docs/latest/tectonic-prometheus-operator/user-guides/configuring-prometheus-alertmanager.html#editing-the-configuration
I don't think that simple

Comment: @Mher Arsh could you elaborate your need in Question? What exactly you want to achieve and what you already did.

Answer (score 0):

One such application is Promgen. It seems to work pretty well overall, but I have had trouble understanding its design choices, and have struggled to get it up and running a couple times. Their docker-compose files are for testing purposes and as such don't work straight out of the box and require some heavy changes and understanding of the inner workings. Their documentation also doesn't seem to be updated. But with enough reading and troubleshooting, you should be able to get this up and running.

https://github.com/line/promgen